# Boundedness of $\log(\|A^{-1}\|)/\log(\|A\|)$ as $A$ ranges over $SL(n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis, matrix-calculus

I wonder if the quantity $\frac{\log(\|A^{-1}\|)}{\log(\|A\|)}$  is bounded by a constant number that only depends on the size $n$ of the matrix as $A$ ranges over $SL(n,\mathbb R)$ (the determinant one matrices). I couldn't find a counterexample, nor can I prove it.

Here I require $\|\cdot \|$ as the operator norm of the matrix w.r.t the 2-norm of the Euclidean spaces. I am not sure if the answer is the same regardless of the norm of the matrix. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer I want, but this should be true for the spectral norm. If $A\in SL(n,\mathbb R)$, then so is $A^{T} A$, and we sort its spectrum as follows:

$$0< |a_1| \le \cdots \le |a_n|.$$

Since the product $|a_1 \cdots a_n|=1$, we have $|a_1 a_n^{n-1}|\ge 1$. Therefore

$$\frac{\log(\|A^{-1}\|)}{\log(\|A\|)}\le \frac{\log(|a_1^{-1}|)} {\log(|a_n|)}\le 
\frac{\log(|a_1^{-1}|)} {\log(|a_n|)} \le n-1.$$

Let me know of any mistake.

Comment: well, it is not true that $||A^{-1}||$ is bounded above by $|a_1|^{-1}$; take for example $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1& 100\\ 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$$Also, it is unclear how do you outrule the case $||A||=1$ (or very close), when denominator is zero...

Comment: I am dealing with the spectrum norm. Your 100 matrix has norm 1 in terms of this. The numerator and denominator both go to zero in this case...

Comment: I don't know what's a "spectral norm". The modulus of the largest eigenvalue is not a norm, as it is zero for a non-zero matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: Sorry that is my mistake... I was talking about the spectral radius, not norm... I will leave this wrong answer here for a while for the record purpose. Thanks @Kostya_I

Comment: This proof is fine. The norm of $A$ is its largest singular value, which is the square root of the largest eigenvalue ("spectral radius") of $A^T A$. Be careful to distinguish when you are talking about $A$ and when you are talking about $A^T A$.